# Error al sacar dato desde una relacion con laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo 2 tablas `users` y `roles`, estoy tratando con laravel sacar el nombre del rol el cual posee mi usuario, este es mi `Model` de roles

```
class Role extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'roles';

    public function user(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\User');

    }

}
```

Relacion `Model User`

```
public function role(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Role', 'id');
}
```

trato de obtener el dato usando:

```
$user = \Auth::user();

echo $user->id_role->name;
```

Si uso unicamente:

```
echo $user->id_role;
```

me trae los datos sin problemas, el inconveniente es para sacar los datos de la tabla role. Me arroja el error

> Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: agrega como estas intentando sacar los datos de la tabla rol

Comment: ya lo puse pana, intento `echo $user->id_role->name;`

Comment: ¿cómo está definida la relación en el modelo User?

Comment: ya lo agregue pana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitaría ver la definicion de las tablas pero en principio para usar la relación tenés que llamar a la relación y no lo estás haciendo.

Deberías de hacer

```
$user->role->name;
```

Mi recomendación es que uses una relación [Many to Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) para hacer esto. De hecho el ejemplo de este tipo de relación en la documentación es con usuarios y roles.

**Tabla `users`**
- id
- name

**Tabla `roles`**
- id
- name

**Tabla `role_user`**
- id
- role_id
- user_id

**Modelo `User`**

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this
        ->belongsToMany('App\Role');
}
```

**Modelo `Role`**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this
        ->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

Con esto te funciona seguro

```
foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
    echo $role->name;
}
```

Comment: Hermano 2 min antes de tu repuesta lo pude resolver de esta manera, en mi function `role` `return $this->belongsTo('App\Role', 'id_role');` y en mi function `user` `return $this->hasMany('App\User');` y lo llamo `echo $user->role->name;`, aunque no tengo muy claro porque es `$user->role->name` y no `$user->id_role->name`, me podrias explicar?

Comment: bueno, con este comentario estás brindando la información que necesitaba para contestar correctamente tu problema. 
Te explico por que pero te recomiendo también que mires un par de tutoriales al respecto para que vayas entendiendo mas.  Al parecer en tu tabla **`users`** tenés un campo **'id_role'** (te recomiendo que lo llames `role_id` para seguir los estandares de Laravel) si vos hacés `$user->id_role` vas a tener como respuesta el **`id`** del rol de ese usuario. No es una colección ni un objeto sino un entero por ende no existe el atributo **`name`**

Comment: y es por esto que necesitás una relación **`belongsTo`**  para acceder a los atributos del role correspondiente. Entonces definiendo el método role podés acceder a los atributos de el rol del usuario.

Comment: Espero haber podido explicar claramente y en pocas palabras el porque

Comment: excelente, gracias por la explicacion

Answer (score 1):

La relación desde Role no es correcta, tu tienes esto

```
public function role(){
   return $this->hasMany(App\Role::class);
}
```

Cuando debiera de ser:

```
public function role(){
   return $this->belongsTo(App\Role::class);
}
```

Para recuperar el nombre de role solo tienes que hacer algo como:

```
$user->role->name;
```